# Running a .desktop file in the terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, .desktop

From what I can gather, `.desktop` files are shortcuts that allow application's settings to be customized. For instance, I have lots of them in my `/usr/share/applications/` folder.

If I open that folder in `nautilus`, I can run these applications just by double clicking its associated file, e.g. double-clicking `firefox.desktop` runs Firefox. However, I can't find a way to do the same thing via terminal.

If I do `gnome-open foo.desktop` it simply opens `foo.desktop` as a text file. If I make it executable and then run it in bash it simply fails (which is expected, it's clearly not bash script).
EDIT: Doing `exec /fullpath/foo.desktop` gives me a `Permission denied` message, even if I change ownership to myself. If I make executable and do the same command, the terminal tab I'm using simply closes (I'm guessing it crashes). Finally, if I do `sudo exec /fullpath/foo.desktop`, I get an error reporting `sudo: exec: command not found`.

That's my question, how can I run a `foo.desktop` file from the terminal?

Comment: NB: The reason your `exec` failed is because exec replaces your currently running process with the process you specify, so what you did was try to replace your shell with running the desktop as a compiled binary. The reason you couldn't `sudo exec` is because it's a shell builtin and not a binary command.

Comment: Interesting, I was wondering why it caused the tab to close.

Comment: Related: [Hashbang for Gnome .desktop files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020106/hashbang-for-gnome-desktop-files)

Comment: I see, they end up parsing the .desktop file. Thank you anyway for the link.

Comment: straightforward and tested answer below from 2019 with 6 options: https://askubuntu.com/a/1114798/795299

Answer (score 87, accepted):

### Modern Answer

`gtk-launch <app-name>` - where `<app-name>` is the file name of the `.desktop` file, with or without the `.desktop` extension.

See [another answer on this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/385169/150) for more details.  *I got this info from that answer.*

### Deprecated shell tools answer

*Written a long time ago - see the comments below this answer as to why this approach won't work for many desktop files.*

The command that is run is contained inside the desktop file, preceded by `Exec=` so you could extract and run that by:

```bash
$(grep '^Exec' filename.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' \
| sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
```

To break that down

```bash
grep  '^Exec' filename.desktop    # - finds the line which starts with Exec
| tail -1                         # - only use the last line, in case there are 
                                  #   multiple
| sed 's/^Exec=//'                # - removes the Exec from the start of the line
| sed 's/%.//'                    # - removes any arguments - %u, %f etc
| sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g' # - removes " around command (if present)
$(...)                            # - means run the result of the command run 
                                  #   here
&                                 # - at the end means run it in the background
```

You could put this in a file, say `~/bin/deskopen` with the contents

```bash
#!/bin/sh
$(grep '^Exec' $1 | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' \
| sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &
```

Then make it executable

```bash
chmod +x ~/bin/deskopen
```

And then you could do, e.g.

```bash
deskopen /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-about.desktop
```

The arguments (`%u`, `%F` etc) are detailed [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html#exec-variables). None of them are relevant for launching at the command line.

Comment: This gives the best result so far, but it produces undesirable behavior sometimes. It happens whenever the "Exec=" line has an argument like %u or %i. Bash tries to pass that string as a regular argument. For instance, doing `grep '^Exec' firefox.desktop | sed 's/^Exec=//'` opens Firefox with a tab that loads *www.%u.com*.

Comment: For the moment I've added a second `sed` to remove any arguments. But I think there might be a more "natural" way to run it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the extra sed - I forgot the desktop files could have arguments.

Comment: You should add a "tail -1" to the pipe after "grep" , since "Exec=" can be appear multiple time , and after that , only the last appearance should be executed ..

Comment: @warl0ck: thanks for that - I've updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: -1: This may work for simple `.desktop` files, but it ignores entries like `Path=` and `TryExec=` which may affect execution. It also executes the wrong `Exec=` if the file contains Desktop Actions ("quicklists")

Comment: It doesn't show the icon of the application. Is this an expected behaviour or I should have something wrong in some file?

Comment: This didn't worked for me. It seems any paths are double quoted. The script by Carlo worked.

Comment: This gave me problems with vlc.desktop, it had an option in the form of `--started-from-file`. I added another pipe to strip that: `sed 's/-.*//g'`... I barely know how to use sed, so I don't  know if this is without problems.

Comment: hackish hack is hacky - need solution that causes the desktop to run it

Comment: This answer fails when the exec string ended in a double quote mark. It removed the last one but left the first one. For example: `Exec=su-to-root -c "/usr/local/bin/ddm-mx -i nvidia"` resulted in: `su-to-root -c "/usr/local/bin/ddm-mx -i nvidia`.

Comment: @BobC yep, just change the two last seds to:
`sed 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/g'`

Comment: I like your "Deprecated shell tools answer", which, albeit imperfect for all cases, works for most desktop files. So, I've upvoted your answer and [put that script into my own summary answer too](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114798/327339).

Comment: For those who found that answer by googling and wanted to start desktop file, for `gtk-launch` the file has to be located in certain folders, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393079/gtk-launch-only-works-when-present-working-directory-is-desktop

Answer (score 152):

### [gtk-launch](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-launch.html)

With any recent Ubuntu that supports `gtk-launch` just simply go

```
gtk-launch <file>
```

Where `<file>` is the name of the `.desktop` file with or without the `.desktop` part. The name must **not** include the full path.

The `.desktop` file must be in `/usr/share/applications`, `/usr/local/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`.

So `gtk-launch foo` opens `/usr/share/applications/foo.desktop` (or `foo.desktop` located in one of the other permitted directories.)

From `gtk-launch` [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-launch.html):

> **gtk-launch** launches an application using the given name. The application is started with proper startup notification on a default display, unless specified otherwise.
>
> **gtk-launch** takes at least one argument, the name of the application to launch. The name should match application desktop file name, as residing in /usr/share/application, **with or without the '.desktop' suffix**.

Usable from terminal or <kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> (<kbd>Alt + F2</kbd> stores command in history so it's easily accessible).

Comment: gtk-launch firefox.desktop  ~/.local/share/applications/ launches firefox *viewing the directory ~/.local/share/applications/* for me.  Seems if you were correct, firefox should not have been passed the directory of the .desktop file as an argument.  In fact the directory passed to gtk-launch is not supposed to be used to locate the dir containing the .desktop file (and is not, in fact)

Comment: This DOES work for me in Arch Linux also. None of the other answers were satisfactory, but this one is good. :-) It works even though I am running KDE.

Comment: No version of this works for me on Ubuntu 18.10. Everytime it complains the application doesn't exist, whether I'm in the folder with the desktop file or not, whether I include the .desktop extension or not, and whether I separately name the directory or not.

Comment: @ Joseph, I didn't add that part about providing a path, some one else did and probably is wrong. The .desktop needed to be in an applications folder as noted. (/usr/share/applications, /usr/local/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: well that's utterly pointless. the only real point to would be to launch user-made .desktop launchers. if your app is in `/usr/local/share/applications` then you can just type the name of the app in the terminal.

Comment: @JosephGarvin Okay I figured it out, it's gtk-launch MYCUSTOMAPP.desktop without the path. works on ubuntu 18.10

Comment: The files could be even in any data dir specified in https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking for a way to bypass [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/117), while still making use of the .desktop files (for things like `%U` handling), and `gtk-launch` worked perfectly. I did download and install the patched version of Nautilus from the MR linked there, but it's great to have a solution that works without downgrading a core system (in terms of GNOME) application.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for files in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: Ah! `kioclient5 exec ~/.local/share/applications/myprogram.desktop` worked for me on Kubuntu 20.04. See [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/425178) if you're on KDE.

Comment: this is a Gnome specific answer, if you DE is not GNOME it will force you to load unneeded libraries to make it work, I strongly suggest to use the @Carlo Pellegrini answer and use glib gio

Answer (score 107):

The answer should be

```
xdg-open program_name.desktop
```

But due to [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xdg-utils/+bug/378783) ([here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/issues/54) upstream, closed on 2020-12-09) this no longer works.

Comment: On GNOME you can use gnome-open which in turn uses xdg-open which has the bug.

Comment: WoW this is still a bug, lots of progress in xdg.  `exo-open` is listed as workaround and it opens gedit too.  :(

Comment: @RichardHolloway: `gnome-open`does *not* call `xdg-open`, it's the other way around! So the issue lies in `gvfs-open` (the successor or `gnome-open`)

Comment: "no longer works"? It never did! `xdg-open` works by mimetype association, and `.desktop` files are associated with text editors, since they are a subclass of text

Comment: this is so stupid (that there is no sensible way to run a Desktop file from the terminal)

Comment: This bug is still there huh?

Comment: Works for me on Arch Linux, but maybe it's an Ubuntu-specific bug.

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Ubuntu 16.04. Just opens the `.desktop` file in gedit.

Comment: This does NOT work for me in Arch Linux at this time. `xdg-open program_name.desktop` opens the desktop file in a text edtor.

Comment: same ubuntu 18.10 still opens gedit

Comment: Works for me in 18.04 using Xubuntu. According to the help output of xdg-open and xdg-mime it shouldn't.

Comment: Can `exo-open` be installed as a standalone package on Ubuntu without pulling in all of XFCE? I ask because in Opensuse `exo-tools` is a standalone package, with only minimal dependencies on XFCE (I think just one core library).

Comment: If it works for you, it's likely you have associated desktop files with some launcher, instead of a text editor.

Comment: Works for me on linux mint 20.3

Answer (score 66):

Since [glib 2.67.2](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/releases/2.67.2) there's a `gio launch` command that can be used like this:

```
gio launch ./foo.desktop
```

---

For older releases I've got a quick workaround (stealing inspiration from the nautilus source code). It is a bit convoluted, but works flawlessly on Ubuntu 12.10, adding a meaningful icon (no more `?`) on the Unity launcher.

First, I wrote a python script using Gio and placed saved it as `~/bin/run-desktop` :

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from gi.repository import Gio
import sys 

def main(myname, desktop, *uris):
    launcher = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename(desktop)
    launcher.launch_uris(uris, None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv)
```

The script needs  to have the executable permission, so I ran this in a terminal:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/run-desktop
```

Then I created the relative `.desktop` entry on `~/.local/share/applications/run-desktop.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=run-desktop
Exec=run-desktop %U
MimeType=application/x-desktop
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Finally, I associated the entry as the default handler in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` under the `[Default Applications]` section as :

```
[Default Applications]
....
application/x-desktop=run-desktop.desktop
```

Now:

- `xdg-open` something.desktop works as expected
- `#!/usr/bin/xdg-open`
  hashbang on top of an executable desktop entry works too

Comment: This works better than [Hamish Downer's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/5174/2355) as it will deal with multiple `Exec=` lines and `%` parameters in the command correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the code - I'm on Lucid, and I simply saved this as `/usr/bin/xdg-openpy`, and gave it a `chmod +x` - and used `launcher.launch([],context)` instead of `...None,context)` (because of "_TypeError: argument 1: Must be sequence, not NoneType_"). Now `xdg-openpy app.desktop` works from command line (and all as normal when double-clicking `app.desktop`), and it can remind me if I try to call in terminal `xdg-open` and press tab. Cheers!

Comment: +1. This is the only answer that does not require manually parsing the `.desktop` file, so it's the most sane (and safe) approach. Also uses modern `gi.repository` instead of the deprecated `pygtk`, so great! :)

Comment: *In fact, this is a question concerning Carlo Pellegrini's answer. I'm a newby, please correct me if there was a better way to place it.* The script works really fine, but the icon I get on the Unity launcher is not the icon defined in the .desktop file but the the default icon of the 'Exec'ed command. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt did you ever find a fix to that? I'm also trying to get the icon to be that of the `.desktop` file.

Comment: @noitidart unfortunately not, I've learned to live with it and haven't made any more efforts

Comment: Thanks @IngoLeonhardt for the reply! I'm actually finding lots of documentation on Gio and it has a lot of stuff mentioning `icon` (such as `gdk_app_launch_context_set_icon_name`) I think this is very possible! Did you explore the `Gio` docs? I'm reading code here: https://github.com/mathitme/nautilus/blob/2944be953ef54717bb24968b0eebe468c9705db4/libnautilus-private/nautilus-program-choosing.c#L142

Comment: @noitidart my concern was starting things like specially parametrized xterms with a different icons to be able to distinguish one form another. So I haven't looked at C code. Nevertheless if you find something I would be glad if you let me know

Comment: Will definitely keep you updated @IngoLeonhardt :) I badly need the custom icon solution :)

Comment: Hey @IngoLeonhardt I figured out the c code to do this and it does launch with the custom icon! This is firefox js-ctypes code. To run it you can follow this youtube vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rzgf7-I5QPg are you sure the icon of the .desktop file was not used?

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I tested launching .desktop file on Ubuntu 14.04 and it launched and the custom icon of the .desktop took everywhere. But on Mint Cinnamon 17.1 the .desktop file if double clicked or if launched with `Gio` it doesn't take the icon of the .desktop. I'm thinking of looking into using `gdk_app_launch_context_set_icon_name` with Gio launch_uris, maybe it will make it take the icon, any idea?

Comment: @Noitidart not at the moment (and not too much time either). But I've updated my run-desktop to the current version of this answer and still gnome-terminal is launched with it's default icon, not the one form the .desktop (Ubuntu 14.04 too)

Comment: @Noitidart write the last answer led mo to do some google and I found [that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55047/set-a-custom-icon-for-gnome-terminal). Haven't checked it out, but maybe it helps

Comment: xseticon looks interesting it must be a custom function which sets `_NET_WM_ICON`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yep XChangeProperty is how they do it i downloaded that file: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/64ad2edbda32627b684f

Answer (score 63):

While OP was not asking about KDE, for anyone that is running KDE the following command can be used:

`kioclient exec <path-to-desktop-file>`

On Fedora, this is included in the [kde-runtime](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/kde-runtime/kde-runtime/) rpm. On Arch, it is in [kde-cli-tools](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/kde-cli-tools/) (HT: @Aron Cederholm).

Comment: Upvoted because it works. No need to be running KDE at all, as long as you have this program installed.

Comment: Is there a way to have stdout of this ? I have compiled clementine player, which has a bug that occurs only launching through .desktop file (with plasma-shell). And i can't figure out, how to have output log log anywere.

Comment: @Kwaadpepper you could use your .desktop file to launch a shell script, which internally runs your command and redirects output to a file.

Comment: I do not find kioclient in any package of KDE for Arch Linux at this time. However, gtk-launch works under KDE for me.

Comment: `kioclient5 exec ~/.local/share/applications/myprogram.desktop` worked for me on Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: @geekley It worked in KDE Neon 5.22.4 (Ubuntu 20.04) as well.

Comment: @MountainX, it is located in package [kde-cli-tools](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/kde-cli-tools/)

Answer (score 43):

You could use [dex](https://github.com/jceb/dex): generate and execute Application type .desktop files.

> **D**esktop**E**ntry e**X**ecution implements the Freedesktop.org autostart specification, independent of any desktop or window manager environment.
> Applications may be filtered based on the Desktop Environment advertised in the .desktop file.

Install dex:

```
sudo apt install dex
```

Run the file with it:

```
dex foo.desktop
```

Comment: IMHO this is exactly the right answer: One tool, a single call with only the file as parameter. That's what I was looking for, too, to test hand-written `.desktop` files. And it can create `.desktop` files, too, yay! :-)

Comment: Perfect!    If you add a .desktop file that uses dex  https://gist.github.com/stuaxo/4169fc1342c496b7c8f7999188f2f242  to  /usr/share/applications/   you will be able to launch desktop files in the filemanager without them opening in gedit by default too.

Comment: `$ dex chromium.desktop` yields: `File does not exist: /home/$USER/chromium.desktop`. This solution isn't very portable, you're otherwise forced to use `$ dex /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop`. `gtk-launch` works without the full path.

Answer (score 42):

## The Right Way

You should really be using `gtk-launch` if it is available. It is usually part of the package **libgtk-3-bin** (this may vary by distro).

`gtk-launch` is used as follows:

```bash
gtk-launch APPLICATION [URI...]
gtk-launch app-name.desktop
gtk-launch app-name
```

Please note that `gtk-launch` requires the *.desktop* file to be installed (i.e. located in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`).

So to get around this, we can use a hackish little Bash function that temporarily installs the desired *.desktop* file before launching it. The "correct" way to install a *.desktop* file is via `desktop-file-install` but I'm going to ignore that.

```bash
launch(){

    # Usage: launch PATH [URI...]

    # NOTE: The bulk of this function is executed in a subshell, i.e. `(..)`
    #       This isn't strictly necessary, but it keeps everything
    #       out of the global namespace and lessens the likelihood
    #       of side effects.

    (

    # where you want to install the launcher to
    appdir=$HOME/.local/share/applications

    # the template used to install the launcher
    template=launcher-XXXXXX.desktop

    # ensure $1 has a .desktop extension, exists, is a normal file, is readable, has nonzero size
    # optionally use desktop-file-validate for stricter checking
    # desktop-file-validate "$1" 2>/dev/null || {
    [[ $1 = *.desktop && -f $1 && -r $1 && -s $1 ]] || {
        echo "ERROR: you have not supplied valid .desktop file" >&2
        return 1
    }

    # ensure the temporary launcher is deleted upon exit
    trap 'rm "$launcherfile" &>/dev/null' EXIT

    # create a temp file to overwrite later
    launcherfile=$(mktemp -p "$appdir" "$template")

    launchername=${launcherfile##*/}

    # overwrite temp file with the launcher file
    if cp "$1" "$launcherfile" &>/dev/null; then
        gtk-launch "$launchername" "${@:2}"
    else
        echo "ERROR: failed to copy launcher to applications directory" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    )

}
```

You can use it like so (and also pass along additional arguments or URIs if you want):

```bash
launch PATH [URI...]
launch ./path/to/shortcut.desktop
```

---

## The Manual Alternative

If you want to manually parse and execute a *.desktop* file, you can do so with the following `awk` command:

```bash
awk '/^Exec=/ {sub("^Exec=", ""); gsub(" ?%[cDdFfikmNnUuv]", ""); exit system($0)}' app-name.desktop
```

If you want to treat the `awk` command like an all-in-one script; we can even show an error message and exit with a return code of 1 in the event that an *Exec* command is not found:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {command=""} /^Exec=/ {sub("^Exec=", ""); gsub(" ?%[cDdFfikmNnUuv]", ""); command=$0; exit} END {if (command!="") {exit system(command)} else {if (FILENAME == "-") {printf "ERROR: Failed to identify Exec line\n" > "/dev/stderr"} else {printf "ERROR: Failed to identify Exec line in \047%s\047\n", FILENAME > "/dev/stderr"} close("/dev/stderr"); exit 1}}'
```

The aforementioned commands will:

1. Find the line starting with *Exec=*
2. Remove *Exec=*
3. Remove any Exec variables (e.g. `%f`, `%u`, `%U`). It is possible to replace these with positional arguments as the specification intends, but doing so would add significant complexity to the problem. See latest [Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html).
4. Execute the command
5. Immediately exit with the appropriate exit code (so as to not execute multiple *Exec* lines)

Note, this AWK script addresses a few edge cases that may or may not be properly addressed by some of the other answers. Specifically, this command removes multiple *Exec* variables (taking care not to otherwise remove the % symbol), will only execute a single *Exec* line command, and will behave as expected even if the *Exec* line command contains one or more equals sign (e.g. `script.py --profile=name`).

Just a few other caveats... According to the specification, *TryExec* is:

> Path to an executable file on disk used to determine if the program is actually installed. If the path is not an absolute path, the file is looked up in the $PATH environment variable. If the file is not present or if it is not executable, the entry may be ignored (not be used in menus, for example).

With that in mind, it doesn't make sense to execute it's value.

Some other concerns are *Path* and *Terminal*. *Path* consists of the working directory to run the program in. *Terminal* is a boolean that indicates whether the program is run in a terminal window. These can all be addressed, but there's no sense in reinventing the wheel as there are already implementations of the spec. If you do want to implement *Path*, keep in mind that `system()` spawns a subprocess, so you can't change working directory by doing something like `system("cd \047" working_directory "\047"); system(command)`. However you could presumably do something like `system("cd \047" working_directory "\047 && " command)`. Note \047 are single quotes (so the command doesn't break on paths with spaces).

## The Python Alternative

I'm stealing a page from Carlo [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/335327), who suggested creating a Python script to make use of the *gi* module. Here's a minimal way to execute the same code from the shell without having to create a file and worry about I/O.

```python
launch(){

# Usage: launch PATH [URI...]

python - "$@" <<EOF
import sys
from gi.repository import Gio
Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename(sys.argv[1]).launch_uris(sys.argv[2:])
EOF

}
```

Then execute the launcher function as follows:

```bash
launch ./path/to/shortcut.desktop
```

Note the use of URIs is optional. Also, no error checking is performed so you'll want to ensure the launcher exists and is readable (before using it) if you want your script to be durable.

Comment: But the `awk` command is nice. Therefore a +1

Comment: What is a URI in this context? I have a desktop file in an arbitrary folder. How the heck do I just run gtk-launch on it without having to wrap it in some other script? This is maddening.

Comment: This `awk` solution will not properly work if the command has double-escaped whitespaces or backslashes. It breaks on this: `Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/path/to/.wine" wine c:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /path/to/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Рабочий\\ стол/appname.lnk`
And `dex` solution works fine.

Comment: I like the Python solution. No messing about with string operations, thus avoiding some shell argument pitfalls.

Answer (score 21):

```
exo-open [[path-to-a-desktop-file]...]
```

seems to work in 13.10 release, if exo-utils is installed (like is the case with Xubuntu).

Comment: Yes, just tested it in Ubuntu Studio 14.04. BTW. xdg-open and gvfs-open work there, too.

Answer (score 15):

(Compiled from the various other answers here)

Depending on your system, and the various bugs that may or may not exist on your system, try the following until one of them works:

1. `xdg-open program_name.desktop`
2. `exo-open program_name.desktop` [my preferred choice, whenever it works]
3. `gtk-launch program_name.desktop`
4. `kioclient exec program_name.desktop`
5. `dex program_name.desktop`
6. `gio launch program_name.desktop`

   See [@Carlo Pellegrini's answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/327339).
   See the help menu with `gio -h`, and the manual pages with `man gio`.
7. Or, [here's a command from @Hamish Downer](https://askubuntu.com/a/5174/327339) which `grep`-searches the *.desktop file for the `Exec=` line containing the command to execute, removes parts of that line we don't want, then executes it. It is well-written and works well for most desktop files. See [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/5174/327339) for a full explanation of it.

   ```bash
   # To execute the `Exec=` cmd from filename.desktop in the background
   $(grep '^Exec' filename.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' \
   | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &

   # Or, remove the `&` at the end to execute it in the foreground so you 
   # can see output from running the command too
   $(grep '^Exec' filename.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' \
   | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g')
   ```

Note that on Ubuntu systems, your "start menu" desktop launchers are available in `/usr/share/applications/`.

As an example, to show which of the above commands do or don't work on my Ubuntu 14.04 system, here are the results of the following calls for me:

1. `xdg-open /usr/share/applications/eclipse_for_cpp.desktop` # Fails due to bug (tries to have me save this .desktop file)
2. `exo-open /usr/share/applications/eclipse_for_cpp.desktop` # Works
3. `gtk-launch /usr/share/applications/eclipse_for_cpp.desktop` # Fails with "gtk-launch: no such application"
4. `kioclient exec /usr/share/applications/eclipse_for_cpp.desktop` # Works
5. `dex /usr/share/applications/eclipse_for_cpp.desktop` # Fails, & `sudo apt install dex` cannot locate package dex
6. `$(grep '^Exec' /usr/share/applications/eclipse_for_cpp.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//' | sed 's/^"//g' | sed 's/" *$//g') &` # Works

Comment: To make this complete, you should add `gio launch <path to .desktop file>` which supports using a custom .desktop file at any location (https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/916841).

Comment: @ChrisN, good addition. Thank you. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

*Addendum to Hamish's answer.*

Given the deskopen script, you can use a reference to it as the shebang line in a *.desktop* file, since the comment character is still `#`. That is to say, put this as the first line of the *.desktop* file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env deskopen
```

Then flag the *.desktop* file as executable (e.g. with a `chmod +x whatever.desktop`), and then you can

```
path/to/whatever.desktop
```

and *voilà* -- The app will open! (Complete with the icon file I specified, though I have no idea how.)

Now, if you also want deskopen to pass through any command-line parameters, you can instead use this slightly-modified version:

```
#!/bin/sh
desktop_file=$1
shift
`grep '^Exec' "${desktop_file}" | sed 's/^Exec=//' | sed 's/%.//'` "$@" &
```

As an aside, I tried using `"#{@:2}"` instead of `shift`ing, but it kept giving me 'bad substitution'...

Comment: I know this is more appropriately a comment to Hamish's answer, but I'm a new user and not allowed to comment. Oh well!

Comment: If you have the reputation, the most appropriate action would be to edit that answer, actually.

Comment: Strike that, anyone can suggest edits, even users who haven't logged in! It's no biggie any way.

Comment: you can use `"${@:1}"` instead of `shift`, but that requires `bash` instead of `sh` in your `#!` shebang. IMHO your original shift approach is simpler and better

Comment: I did as you said I created the shell. and in my desktop file i added the shebang at top. But its not opening with the icon i set on the .desktop file :( I can share a screencast of my situation if you are available :)

Answer (score 8):

I don't have an immediate solution meeting the requirement for *"using a standard command"*, but if you did want to minimally parse the `.desktop` files or wanted to create a Bash alias, then the following should work:

- `awk -F= '/Exec=/{system($2); exit}' foo.desktop`

another approach that might be interesting, would be to create a kernel-level `binfmt-misc` method than matches on `.desktop` files (see `grep -r . /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/` for those patterns that you currently have enabled).

At the end of the day, *something* somewhere will have to parse the `.desktop` files, it's just a question of how "standard/default" that is.

Comment: Thank you, interesting. As "standard" I mean something provided by the DE and conforming to freedesktop.org.

Comment: Upvote for `awk` rather than a chain of `grep`s and `sed`s.

Comment: Upvote, although it doesn't work (or better put - works too much) if you have  ultiple `Exec=` lines :/

Answer (score 6):

There isn't currently an application that does what you describe in the Ubuntu archives.  There are a couple efforts in progress to create a general solution to provide integration for desktop environments (like openbox) that are not compliant with these XDG specifications.

Arch Linux is working on an implementation of xdg-autostart based on the python-xdg libraries.  From what I can find, this seems not yet entirely complete, but has some reports of success.

There is also a C++ implementation of xdg-autostart on gitorious (http://gitorious.org/xdg-autostart/) which would likely benefit from wider use.

If either solution works for you, please consider submitting the necessary work for inclusion in either Debian or Ubuntu.

To use either tool with openstart, you would call it in /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart.sh (if I am reading the openbox documentation correctly).  If this doesn't work, you can probably call it in any of the openbox session initialisation scripts.

Comment: Not what I would to hear, anyway thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020161/724199) is what made it clear for me: don't try to execute the desktop file, execute the file pointed to in the desktop file.

For example, execute /home/jsmith/Desktop/x11vnc.sh

```
Exec=/home/jsmith/Desktop/x11vnc.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Hamish's answer is great, but I'd like suggest a simpler alternative, with less piping involved:

`$(awk -F= '/^Exec/||/^TryExec/ {print $2;exit}' /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop)`

In this case, `awk` searches for line starting with `Exec`, and then we simply print fields after that line, using for loop and `=` we print field 2, i.e., whatever comes after that field. The curly brackets on the ends of the commands,  `$(...)`, are parameter substitution, thus shell will execute whatever awk command returns; in this case, it returns actual command that comes after `Exec=`.

In some rare cases there may be more than one `=` sign, which is still a possibility. For that, I suggest

```
$(awk -F= '/^Exec/||/^TryExec/ {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i;exit}' /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop)
```

Comment: Nice, `awk` and Serg =)

Comment: And sometimes, there is a `TryExec`, maybe you should check your 2nd command =)

Comment: @A.B.  Hehe, `awk` is my weapon of choice when it comes to text processing.  Besides, it's syntax is close to `C`.  Oh, and already added `TryExec` part ^_^

Comment: But what's about `%f`, `%u`, `%U` or something like this behind the command?

Comment: @A.B. that will be treated as part of a field, because `=` is the separator.  So, for instance if we have `Exec=firefox %u`, then $1 is `Exec` , separator is `=` and $2 is `firefox %u`

Answer (score 2):

I took the script from [Carlo's](https://askubuntu.com/users/114137/carlo-pellegrini) [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/421256) above, and made an attempt to improve on it for my own desktop use.

This version of the script will allow you to run any app as if you entered it on the HUD, so long as it's likely to be the first result.  It also lets you pass file arguments for .desktop files that do not support URIs.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from gi.repository import Gio
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys, os

def find_app(search_string):
    for group in Gio.DesktopAppInfo.search(search_string):
        for entry in group:
            try:
                return Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new(entry)
            except: pass
    return None

def main(args):
    launcher = None
    if os.path.isfile(args.appName):
        try:
        # If it's a file, do that first.
            launcher = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename(args.appName)
        except TypeError:
            print "'" + args.appName + "' is not a .desktop file"
            sys.exit(-1)
    # If it's a .desktop file in the DB, try using that
    if launcher is None and args.appName.endswith('.desktop'):
        try:
            launcher = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new(args.appName)
        except TypeError: pass

    if launcher is None:
        # Search for the app by the text given
        launcher = find_app(args.appName)

    if launcher is None:
        print "No app named " + args.appName + " could be found"
        sys.exit(-1)
    if (launcher.supports_uris()):
        launcher.launch_uris(args.uris, None)
    elif (launcher.supports_files()):
        launcher.launch(list({ Gio.File.parse_name(x) for x in args.uris }), None)
    else :
        launcher.launch()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    argParser = ArgumentParser(description="Launch a .desktop file or application")
    argParser.add_argument("appName", 
        help="the name of any application, a desktop file's basename, or a concrete path to a desktop file", 
        action='store'
    )
    argParser.add_argument("uris", 
        nargs='*', 
        help="Files or URIs to pass to the application"
    )
    args = argParser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Answer (score 1):

When trying to test these files I found the simplest way to check that that the DM or session manager would do what I expected was to open the surrounding dir in a UI folder browser and then double-click to open them.

If you are in a command line : `gvfs-open .` or `gnome-open .` will open it in the configured folder browser.

The sed thing will not mirror the DM's behaviour, including fiddly stuff like escapes and quoting where you really wouldn't want alternative behaviour. It's not command line, but it did validate things. I also found setting `Terminal=true` useful for debugging.

Comment: The terminal disappears immediately, I don't have the time to see the message when using Terminal=true :s

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script your desktop file points to is executable too.

If still doesn't work. Make desktop file runnable in terminal by changing `Terminal=true`, and put it inside a bash script. Run the script to catch the error output. Change back when errors are corrected.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience with trying the above answers, `gtk-launch` does not provide any helpful diagnostic information, and is slightly misleading, reporting "not found" as the cause of the error rather than the *real* root cause.  The best I could come up with was installing `rofi` with `sudo apt install rofi` and then launching it from the terminal with:

```
rofi -show drun
```

Then, I selected my application using its fuzzy-finder, and after pressing enter, it *actually* gave me the real reason for why the *.desktop file would not launch (in my case, I had quotes around the Exec-line in my *.desktop file).

Does anybody know where the source-code is for `gtk-launch`? This really seems like we should create a PR for giving better, more accurate error messages, as this seems to be a prevalent problem when searching around the net.

Edit1: I found the `gtk-launch` source [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/tools/gtk-launch.c)

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /usr/share/applications
gio launch program_name.desktop
```

See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/54

Answer (score -1):

"I am using Ubuntu 20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"

Just open the terminal and then navigate to that folder where .desktop file is located and then type

```
chmod +x (name of desktop file)
./(name of desktop file)
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I don't think `.desktop` files have interpreter directives, so, like, won't the shell just unsuccessfully try to execute the file?

Comment: No, this is not working