# How do I "execute" a *.desktop file from a terminal?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal)

Is this even possible?

I fully know I can just copy it to my desktop and double-click it.

Comment: This has been covered on the site before. I don't have a link handy, but a search should give you the questions where it is covered :).

Comment: 1) Google didn't find it - it found a different obscure questions that lead me here.

2) The search box couldn't be more obscure; otherwise, I would have used it. With the "Ask question >" link being so prominent, it doesn't surprise me there are so many duplicates and that you guys get so mad!

3) Sorry, assumed there was auto duplicate checking/verification like most similar systems have.

Comment: Lol I'm not mad :) - and trust me, duplicates aren't usually something that gets us regular contributors mad :P. (I'm just busy, if not I would have the link for you by now :)).

Comment: Ya, mad wasn't the right word, but I have seen a bunch of discussion in meta about them. Oh, and I found it - the site's search worked much better than Google, but even so the dup was down below this one in the results... It is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal for anyone else that comes across this duplicate.