# Start IDEA from menu

Tags: unity-dash

I trying to run IDEA from dash menu. So I've create `.desktop` file for it and put it to `/usr/share/applications`:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IDEA
Comment=IntelliJ IDEA
Exec=/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/opt/idea/bin/idea.png
Terminal=0
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;

$ ls -l /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 179 Oct  3 11:01 /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop
```

When I type `idea` in dash I can see IDEA's icon, but when I click on it application not start. In the same time if i run `/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh` from console, it will run.

How to solve (or debug) this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly, you are missing some environment variables. Maybe some entries in your $PATH? How about the following. Create a script, say `/home/user/testidea.sh` (where `user` is your actual username, of course), containing

```
#!/bin/bash

/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh 2> /tmp/idea.err > /tmp/idea.out
```

Make it executable

```
chmod a+x /home/user/testidea.sh
```

And replace the respective line in the `idea.desktop` file by

```
exec=/home/user/testidea.sh
```

Maybe that will work, but if not, at least (hopefully) you will find what is wrong by inspecting `/tmp/idea.err` and `/tmp/idea.out`.

Comment: Thanks for idea, it was really helpful. In log file i found cause of error: `No JDK found. Please validate either IDEA_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.` I've just add `export JDK_HOME=/opt/jdk` to IDEA's startup script and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start debugging you can try to run the desktop file from command-line and see the response. The topic of how to cover this seems to be covered in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal). The particular solution to try might be using `gnome-open` to see the result but apparently that might not work :(

Second thing to try is if the desktop file works while double clicking from desktop or nautilus?

Finally i found this page about [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) which goes into more detail abt this. Particularly, it suggests you use the [desktop file validator](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/desktop-file-validate.1.html) to check if the file is valid.