# Cannot start Eclipse from Unity Launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, eclipse

I downloaded *Eclipse Juno* package, and extracted it to `/opt` directory. For installing it, I followed the steps given in this site - [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE) under the *User Installation* section. I created the `opt_eclipse.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` directory. Here is the content of my desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=eclipse42
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.20
```

Then I installed the desktop file on Unity using the following command, as given in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/145018/159439):

```
sudo desktop-file-install /usr/share/applications/opt_eclipse.desktop
```

Then I created the symbolic link using the below command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse42
```

I also moved the icon to the pixmaps folder using the below command:

```
cp opt/eclipse/icon.xpm /usr/share/pixmaps/eclipse.xpm
```

Now, when I go to Unity, I can find the Eclipse Icon. But, when I click it, nothing happens. It doesn't get started. I'm completely new to Ubuntu. Did I miss something out there?

Comment: this link worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/80016 > you need to specify the correct path for icon and eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also install the jdk, it is needed for eclipse.

Enter the full path to the start-script in the Desktop-file

`Exec=/path/to/ecplipse/eclipse42`

if the path is noch included in your $PATH-Variable, what normally should note be if you did not by yourself.

Comment: Do we need to give the path till the executables in the `Exec` or till the startup script? And how to see what is there in my $PATH variable. Do I need to add the path to JDK there?

Comment: I installed jdk using - `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.

Comment: if you install jdk by software-center/apt you do not need to add it. to show your $PATH type in terminal: `echo $PATH`

Comment: by the way, it is not needed to eclipse-path to $PATH to get eclipse running

Comment: the Exec-Path on my machine looks this way:
`/home/christian/apps/eclipse/eclipse` this is the file to be called in Desktop-file

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm giving. My path is: `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`

Comment: Are you able to start eclipse in terminal by typing `eclipse42`?

Comment: No. Command not found. :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9234/discussion-between-quidage-and-rohit-jain)

Comment: Thank you so much. Seems like the problem was with symlinks. I created the symlinks to `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`, whereas I installed eclipse in my home directory. Once I changed the symlinks to `~/opt/eclipse/eclipse`, it worked. Thanks for pointing me to that direction. And now I now one more think, RED color with symlinks means - PROBLEM. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need JAVA Runtime Environment installed.
Did you try running eclipse directly by clicking binary?

Comment: I have already installed the JRE. Also, when I run eclipse directly from startup script stored in `~/bin/eclipse`, it is running.

Comment: It is also running from the binary.

Comment: So probably there's something wrong with links i think. How about giving the full path to binary file as `Exec` option?

Comment: Do you mean symbolic links? What might be the problem? I don't know, I just followed the steps on the other posts.

Comment: Try using `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` as `Exec`

Comment: Not working. :(

Comment: Please see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) and tell us if something is written in the console when you run the desktop file

Comment: Is our desktop file allowed to be executed?

Comment: I tried those steps. But when I do - `deskopen /usr/share/applications/opt_eclipse.desktop`, it says - `deskopen: command not found`.

Comment: Ah! My fault. I by mistake also typed a back-tick there. After changing it, it shows a prompt - `rohit@RJ:~$ /opt/eclipse/eclipse` and hangs there with cursor blinking.

Comment: Yes, my desktop file has permission to be executed.

Comment: ok, run in terminal `/opt/eclipse/eclipse` does it work?

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks @Misery. Actually, the problem was with symlinks. (As you said earlier). I wrote the solutions in the comments of first answer. Thanks for helping. :)