# How to simulate an "application launch" (executing a .desktop file) from a script?

Tags: unity, command-line, launcher

This question relates back to separating the Tor Browser from Firefox in the Unity launcher (I assume it applies to other DE's as well). The original question is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2182827).

As part of my proposed solution I created a .desktop file that uses a different icon and runs the Tor Browser as a separate process from firefox.

It seems that in Unity the only way to create separate entries in the launcher/dash is by using separate .desktop files (which makes sense) and putting them in `~./local/share/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`.

However, the problem is that, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal), .desktop files can't/are-not-intended to be run from within a shell, but rather the DE (or something) parses and executes the file and ties it to a particular icon, comment, etc. I want to somehow emulate THAT, whatever the DE does to interpret a .desktop. Something like:

```
$ app-launcher --run-desktop '/path/to/desktop.desktop'
```

I assume things like `Gnome-Do` or `Synapse` use something conceptually similar to my made up command above. So how can I replicate that in a script?

P.D. The best I have been able to come up with is to use `xte` to literally simulate pressing the Super key, typing "Tor Browser" and pressing Enter, as I sit and watch the dash open on its own, "Tor Browser" sluggishly type itself in and finally open the app, all while I gently sob at the horror I have created... There has got to be a better way.  : )

EDIT: Though this question is related to the question: [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal), it is not a duplicate. The other question establishes (as I described in my 4th paragraph) that there is no way to run .desktop files DIRECTLY from a terminal and keep separate entries in the Unity launcher, either due to a bug in `xdg-open` or simply because that is not what they were designed for. Acknowledging that fact, this question asks for a different method for executing .desktop files from a terminal, by using the same (or similar) method the Unity Dash, Gnome-Do or Synapse uses.