# How do I permanently change window titles?

Tags: window-manager, xdotool, wmctrl, xprop

Which files are involved in generating the window title? For example, if you open Rhythmbox, you see the program name as the window title. But it’s not generated by the `.desktop` file. Which file(s) do I need to edit to add text to the title of an application? I want the changes to be permanent

I use Ubuntu GNOME 15.04 with GNOME 3.16.

Comment: Hi Maud. I loved your question, and it has lead to a very nice solution. I cannot resist however to mention one thing to keep in mind for future questions: please do not drastically change the question's meaning *after* answers have been posted. It makes answers, originally adequately posted  on the first version of the question, seemingly misplaced on the edited version. I think that is what actually happened with my answer. I would suggest posting a new question instead, more specifically to your real question if re- think your question.

Comment: I understand your opinion and I certainly will do that with future questions as I can see how it may be quite confusing for people. I  certainly do not underestimate your contribution to the thread, let that be clear. I wanted the title to be more specific as the original title didn't actually cover my real question and raised a bit uncertainty about what my goal was with this thread. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The initial name is usually set by the (code within) the application itself. You can however change it, e.g. by using `xdotool`, which you would have to install first:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

Then, once it is installed, you can set another window name by (e.g.) the command:

```
xdotool search --name "Unity LauncherSwitcher" set_window --name "Monkey"
```

This will change:

[image]

into:

[image]

#### Note

As you can see, the command exists of:

```
xdotool search --name "<current_name>" set_window --name "<new_name>"
```

The `<current_name>` has to match exactly.

---

### Edit *alternatively*

From your comment, I understand the command above did not work. I tested it with different applications, and it worked...

But for a reason I do not understand, NOT with `Rhytmbox`(!! might be a bug)

An alternative is to use `wmctrl`, which you also would have to install:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

Then use the command:

```
xprop -id "$(wmctrl -l | grep 'Rhythmbox' | awk '{ print $1 }')" -set WM_NAME "Music"
```

I succesfully tested it on `Rhythmbox`:

[image]

[image]

#### Make the changes permanent?

As mentioned, the default window name is defined in the code of the application.

Changing the *default* window title would need to change the code. That can be done *if* the code is available, would need recompiling in many cases and depends on the used language, among other things. A general instruction would be quite impossible and beyond (outside) the scope of AU in my opinion.

---

### EDIT 2

#### Flexibly manage/set custom window names per application from a single file

In your original question, you were wondering if there was some kind of a file to set the title of new windows of a specific application. As explained, that is not the case, however, it *can* be created.

In the setup below, you can very easily define on a *per application* base how new windows are named. Simply create a file in `~` (your home directory), named `window_names.txt`. For each of the applications you want to set a specific windowname for, add a line of, subsequenty, the application and the desired window name:

*A textfile, defining window names per application*

```
gnome-terminal Monkey eats
gedit Banana
rhythmbox if he runs out of peanuts
```

[image]

#### Explanation

The setup exists of a simple background script. The script is very light, so it won't have any noticable effect on the performance whatsoever.

Once the script starts, it reads the file `~/window_names.txt` and loads the settings per application. Then it keeps an eye on *newly* created windows. If a window appears that belongs to one of the applications, definied in the file, it sets the window name accordingly.

#### How to set up

1. The script uses both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script into an empty file save it as `setwindowname.py`
3. Create the file `~/window_names.txt` (exactly named `window_names.txt`), add your applications in the format:

   ```
   <application> <window_name>
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   gedit Text editor
   ```

   The window name may include spaces.
4. Test-run the script from the terminal by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/setwindowname.py
   ```
5. If all works as expected, add it to startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add

   Note that in some cases, a script might break if it starts when the desktop is not fully loaded yet. If that migh be the case, the command to add to startup applications would be:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&python3 /path/to/setwindowname.py"
   ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os

f = os.environ["HOME"]+"/"+"window_names.txt"

change = []
lines = open(f).read().splitlines()
for l in lines:
    try:
        change.append([l.split()[0], (" ").join(l.split()[1:])])
    except IndexError:
        pass

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
curr_1 = []

while True:
    try:
        curr_2 = get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines()
        new = [w for w in curr_2 if not w in curr_1]
        for item in new:
            line = item.split(); pid = line[2]
            procs = get(["ps", "-e"]).splitlines()
            match = [l for l in procs if pid in l][0]
            for app in [app for app in change if app[0] in match]:
                subprocess.Popen(["xdotool", "set_window", "--name", app[1], line[0]])
        curr_1 = curr_2
        time.sleep(0.3)
    except:
        pass
```

#### Notes

- If the file `~/window_names.txt` is edited, the script needs to be restarted.
- It works no matter how an application is started; it also works when applications are run from the terminal / and or with `sudo`.
- It does not interefere with the the right-click option of *any* application.
- The script also "maintains" the window name; if another process changes the window name afterwards (opening tabs, change directories e.g.) the script sees the window as a "new window" and maintains the window name of your choice.

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't work for me.

Comment: `xdotool search --name "Rhythmbox" set_window --name "Music"`

I did the command with the application open, closed and did a restart (alt+f2+r) to check if it worked, but it still shows the same window title.

Comment: Wow! This time I'm really impressed! I'll give it a try first thing in the morning. I must say, this looks very promosing :) thanks for your hard work and posting this, Jacob!

Comment: I tried the script exactly as you said, but it doesn't work. Is it possible this won't work with GNOME 3.16 or should it be something in my setup? I'm puzzling with it now and hopefully make it work on my system. If I find the reason why it doesn't function yet, I will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: I ran the check.py from terminal and opened/closed rhythmbox twice. I get the following output:

0x01c00008  0 27728  system Rhythmbox
xprop -id 0x01c00008 -set WM_NAME "if he runs out of peanuts"
0x01c00008  0 27940  system Rhythmbox
xprop -id 0x01c00008 -set WM_NAME "if he runs out of peanuts"

If think that indicates that it works? but why does the window still shows Rhythmbox? See the link for a screenshot: http://we.tl/D8sfzvimiy

Comment: Check.py gives the right output for rhythmbox and gedit as far as I see. I also did run the command again with the ID, but it does nothing. Also gedit is still titled gedit and terminal... well, terminal. Maybe this screenshot will give you some more info: http://we.tl/9LBaqXm42E (I can't make a screenshot with the titles open on plank, but the window title output for gedit is "Untitled Document 2 - gedit" etc.)

Comment: @MaudKon WOW, this works even better on my system, and communicates better with `wmctrl`. Now even window names are "maintained"; if another process changes the name, the script sets it back to what you set.

Comment: Can you please update your answer, so that other people who are searching for this in the future are sparred a headache? ;)

Comment: Running the script at startup is still a problem. I tried `/bin/bash, -c "sleep 15&&python3 /path/to/setwindowname.py"` and `python3 /path/to/setwindowname.py`, but the script doesn't start automatically. Can I add a bash script to open it or do you think there is another option?

Comment: @MaudKon AAARGGGHHH, sorry, sorry, a typo, there should be no comma:   should be: `/bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&python3 /path/to/setwindowname.py"`

Comment: I suddenly get : 

`File "/home/maud/window-names.py", line 7, in <listcomp>
    change = [[l.split()[0], (" ").join(l.split()[1:])]  for l in open(f).read().splitlines()]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @MaudKon You must have edited the settings file, and unintenionally added one or more whitelines, probably at the end. I "immunized" the script for that. You can use as many whitelines as you like now :)

Comment: You're a magician :P It works again :)

Comment: xdotool search --name "Old Name" set_window --name "New name" does not need to be exact, you should update your reply,  it appears to support GNU-style extended regular expressions eg `--name ".+Old Name"` https://askubuntu.com/a/1159489/550832.  @MaudKon   no offence but you have 20 comments in single reply and almost nobody else :)

Answer (score 10):

The title is generated by the application executable and there isn't a easy way to edit it.

---

**Changing the title of a application once it's open:**

- Install `xdotool` with `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
- Get the pid of the application with `pgrep myapp` (i.e. `pgrep rythmbox`)
- Change the window title (replacing `HERE_THE_PID` with the process id of the application):

  ```
  xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid HERE_THE_PID --name "\a\b\c" set_window --name "$new_name"
  ```

**Making a script to launch any application with a custom title:**

- Create a bash script called `change-title` with these contents:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  ## The new name of the window is the first argument passed to the script:
  new_name="${1}"

  ## application is all arguments but the first (the title)
  application=${@:2}

  ## Run the app in background and in quiet mode:
  $application &> /dev/null &

  ## Get the pid of the app:
  app_pid=$!

  ## Wait until the window appears:
  until xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid $app_pid &> /dev/null; do sleep 0.01; done

  ## Change the window name:
  xdotool \
           search \
                  --onlyvisible \
                  --pid $app_pid \
                  --name "\a\b\c" \
           set_window \
                  --name "$new_name"

  ## Comment this line to run the app in background:
  wait $app_pid
  ```
- Make it executable with `chmod a+x change-title`
- Run it with `./change-title "NewTitle" theapp --its-arguments`

**To make the change permanent:**

- Run `gksudo gedit /usr/local/bin/custom-title` (fx. user/local/bin/music)
- On the text editor paste the above script and save it.
- Run `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/custom-title`
- Run `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/rhythmbox.desktop`
- On this file, there is a line (the line number is 35 on mine) that says:

  ```
  Exec=rhythmbox %U
  ```
- Replace it with this with the name of the created file:

  ```
  Exec=custom title (fx. Exec=music)
  ```
- Save the file as a new custom-name.desktop fx. music.desktop. *Be careful that you do not overwrite the original file!*

**To make the change effective for the "open with" function**

- Run `gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/rhythmbox-device.desktop`
- Change `rhythmbox` to the name used in the previous .desktop file.
- Save the file.
- Kill active processes of rhythmbox with system monitor or with `sudo kill rhythmbox`
- Plugin your phone/music player and press "Open with (Music application)" to see if it worked.

**(Summary) Overview of the files you should have**

To make the application fully functional, you should have 3 .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications` when finished:

1. `music.desktop` or the name you gave the application

   with `Exec=music` and `Hidden=true` (add the last one if not present)
2. rhythmbox.desktop

   with `Exec=rhythmbox %U` and `Hidden=true`
3. rhythmbox-device.desktop

   with `Exec=music --select-source %U` and **WITHOUT** the Hidden entry

This means that you always open the last file and the title is always as it should. The only way is resets itself is when you refresh your session with ALT+F2+R.

1. And you should have the bash script in `/usr/local/bin` ofcourse.

**Final notes:**

- When I'm using `--name "\a\b\c"` is to fix [a bug](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/14), don't replace with the application name!
- If do you uncomment the last line of the script, the script will not end until the app is closed.
- Explaination of `${@:2}` in the code requested by [@Maud Kon](https://askubuntu.com/users/403886/maud-kon):

  1. `$@` is an array that stores all the positional parameters.
  2. `${@:2}` means: *All the positional parameters but the first*
  3. Let's say that I call a program this way:

     ```
     awesome-program foo bar baz fooz
     ```

     - `${@:1}` would be `foo bar baz fooz`
     - `${@:2}` would be `bar baz fooz`
     - `${@:3}` would be `baz fooz`
     - `${@:4}` would be `fooz`
     - `${@:5}` is empty because there aren't more positional parameters.
  4. `$@`, `${@}` and `${@:1}` are the same thing: All the positional parameters.
  5. Learn more about this topic here: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams

Comment: I've tried both manners (also the one down here) and your bash script works partially. It launches a new window with the new name, but if I launch it again from overview, it still has the old entry... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MaudKon: What's the overview? Try the script now. If do you call "Overview" to the dash (big panel with many apps), I'll say you that my script doesn't makes a permanent change.

Comment: I mean the applications overview, i've already hidden dash itself, haha. Hmm, yeah, than your script works. Is there anyway to make the change permanent? Like editing an executable file with fx. GHex? Or changing the executable in the .desktop file?

Comment: Try now. Use the new script and follow the method under the section **To make the change permanent**. Now I understood that you're making a *camouflage* of your Ubuntu **;-)**

Comment: Why else would I ask for the title to change ;) some app names are just... yeah... not user friendly :)

Comment: I finally got it to work! adding the script to `/usr/bin/music` and making it executable with `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/music`, allows me to execute the script with 'music'. So what I did is changing `Exec=rhythmbox` to `Exec=music` and that works perfectly fine! :D

Comment: Also @MaudKon note that this will break the (right-click) "open with" option.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I even got that covered now. You can also edit `rhythmbox-device.desktop` and change it to `music --select-source  %U`. That works just fine.

Comment: I am impressed!

Comment: @Helio `change-title` breaks my .desktop file. I got it to work to change the name to `music`.

Comment: @MaudKon: How is your working `Exec` line? Feel free to update my post.

Comment: @Helio I updated your post with the steps that worked for me. I also added the process to make the "open with" function work.

Comment: @Helio can you explain `${@:2}` in your code?

Comment: @MaudKon: Here you're!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24006/discussion-between-maud-kon-and-helio).

Answer (score 2):

## ***Just use the translation file!***

I ran into this very <strike>problem</strike> challenge with Thunar: It became annoying when Compiz Scale displayed the Thunar window title as "AnyFolder - File Manager" and comsumed space with unnecessary information.

I tried the above mentioned ways with `xdotool` and `wmctrl` but they were not permanent since Thunar changes its window title every time I go to another folder. And it felt exaggerated to have a script sitting around in the background to change the title back every time Thunar alters it.

An easier solution was to use the ***translation file*** which comes with every application. You simply need to re-compile the translation source file with a tool called `msgfmt` included in the `gettext` package. I just did this for gThumb -just for fun- and there it works, too.

**1. Get source code for the concerned application.**
Type
`$ sudo apt-get source APPLICATION` or head over to http://packages.ubuntu.com, get the source and look for for a folder called `po`: it contains plain-text language files. Look for your language. Let's say you're from Brazil, that file would be `pt_BR.po`

**2. Alter the file to your needs**
Look for the exact! window title that you want to get rid off or change.
In Thunar's case it was *"File Manager"* and in `pt_BR.po` I found

```
:. set window title
: ../thunar/thunar-window.c:3154 ../Thunar.desktop.in.in.h:3
: ../thunar/thunar-settings.desktop.in.h:1
msgid "File Manager"
msgstr "Gerenciador de arquivos"
```

where `msgid` is the signal the application sends and `msgstr` what the langpack translates it to.
Change `msgstr` to whatever you like, i.e. `msgstr "o_-"`.
I learned that if you leave the translation empty like this `msgstr ""` the application will fall back to `msgid`. If you want it to be "empty" use whitespace. Or a dot. Or any funky ASCII symbol.

**3. Get the compiler**
As mentioned you need `msgfmt` from `gettext` package, so you need to type
`$ sudo apt-get install gettext`

**4. Compile**
Open a terminal, go to the folder with your altered `pt_BR.po` and let msgfmt check the file for errors:
`$ msgfmt --check --check-accelerators=_ -o /dev/null pt_BR.po`
If it's fine, go ahead and compile it:
`$ msgfmt -c -o pt_BR.mo pt_BR.po`

**5. Place file**
Have a look how the original translation in */usr/share/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGE/LC_MESSAGES/*  or */usr/share/locale-langpack/YOUR_LANGUAGE/LC_MESSAGES/* is named and place your file there. If it doesn't exist in both places, put it in one of them and experiment a little with the file name: lowercase, Camelcase or something like , i.e. `gthumb.mo` or `YOUR-APP.mo`.
Make a backup of the original first:
`$ sudo cp /usr/share/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGE/LC_MESSAGES/YOUR-APP.mo /usr/share/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGE/LC_MESSAGES/YOUR-APP.mo.BAK`
then copy your new translation there
`$ sudo cp pt_BR.mo /usr/share/locale/YOUR_LANGUAGE/LC_MESSAGES/YOUR-APP.mo`

If YOUR_APP is running, close all instances of it.
Test It!

**Hint**
If you're running Ubuntu with EN localisation like I am, just use any *.po, delete or comment all unchanged msgid/msgstr couples from it and put it in */usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/*.

Sources:
http://wiki.xfce.org/translations/translation_guidance_in_xfce

Comment: Just for the record; I doubt you actually tried the script, since it *maintains* the name, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: You're right, I didn't try _this_ script but a similiar (simpler) one from somewhere else,  and the tricks with xdotool and wmctrl. As mentioned, for me it feels like shooting sparrows with a cannon, compared to changing **one line** in a source file. Nevertheless, one can learn a lot from the scripts.

Comment: I'm curious what happens if the application is upgraded. Are *.desktop files and localisation files overwritten?

Comment: As explained here http://askubuntu.com/a/703942/72216, I don't share the fobia for a background script, *if* it is well written and *does* add important functionality. About `.desktop` files: again, you must confuse my answer with another one you might have read. The answer does not edit `.desktop` files and no action is needed when an application is reinstalled.

Comment: This was a general question as answer #2 modifies `.desktop` files and I do so wih translation files. Do you know it? And I may give ANY script solution a second chance since I now read i.e. _"mu__Incoming - "_ where I had _"mu__Incoming - File Manager"_. For applications which have a static window title without any "path/to/folder" my solutions works fine.

Comment: @Jacob I couldn't resist to pimp your script so that it's replacing unwanted parts of window titles. It's working for me in Firefox and other applications. Please have a look at it [pastebin.com/kZ7eBx3Q](http://pastebin.com/kZ7eBx3Q), I'm new to Python :) since today

Answer (score 2):

## Replace (parts of) window titles with wmctrl

Since [my own answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/711101/224347) using the application's translation file wasn't sufficient for several cases for me, I built upon [Jacob Vlijm's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/626524/224347) and modified his script to replace certain strings in window titles. I hope it's okay to post this a separate answer. Credits go to **Jacob Vlijm** for the idea and setting up the script!

For example, I like to read `Some fancy website` instead of `Some fancy website - Mozilla Firefox`. Compiz scale plugin is much clearer now as I also removed `- File manager` and other strings.

Changes I made:

1. use `//` as separator in `window_names.txt` to allow white-spaces
2. use `wmctrl` instead of `xdotool` to modify the window title (since xdotool doesn't handle non-ASCII characters very well): `wmctrl -i -r [WindowIdentifier] -N 'new Title'`
3. some extra lines in the script to do the string replacement etc.

The modified `window_names.txt` is structured like this:
`[process name]//[exact text to replace]//[replacement text]`

```
firefox// - Mozilla Firefox// (whitespace!)
thunar// - File Manager// ° xyz
gedit// - gedit// - 123
```

The pimped script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time
import os

f = os.environ["HOME"]+"window_names.txt"

change = []
lines = open(f).read().splitlines()
for l in lines:
    try:
        change.append(l.split("//"))
    except IndexError:
        pass

get = lambda cmd: subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
curr_1 = []

while True:
    try:
        curr_2 = get(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).splitlines()
        new = [w for w in curr_2 if not w in curr_1]

        for item in new:
            line = item.split(None, 4)
            winID = line[0] ; pid = line[2] ; currentTitle = line[4]
            procs = get(["ps", "-e"]).splitlines()
            match = [l for l in procs if pid in l][0]
            for app in [app for app in change if app[0] in match]:
                newTitle = str.replace(currentTitle, app[1], app[2])
                subprocess.Popen(["wmctrl", "-i", "-r", winID, "-N", newTitle])
        curr_1 = curr_2
        time.sleep(0.3)
    except:
        pass
```

Again: Credits go to Jacob Vlijm for the idea and setting up the script!