# Display the current date & time in the window's title

Tags: scripts, window-manager, window, xdotool

Is it currently/technically possible to display the current date & time (ie: digital clock numbers) to the currently active window? Like appending some text from a script?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Showing date & time in the active window's title

Running the script below (an edited version of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/626524/72216)) in the background, the front most window will show the current date & time:

[image]

If the window loses focus, the time will not be updated; only on the front most window, the time *will* be updated.
The script also shows the date & time *per tab* on any application using tabs, like `firefox` or `gnome-terminal`

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

cmd = "xdotool", "getwindowfocus"
get_name = "xdotool", "getactivewindow", "getwindowname"

currtime_1 = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M"); wid_1 = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
wname_1 = subprocess.check_output(get_name).decode("utf-8"); wname_1 = wname_1[:wname_1.rfind(" |  ")]

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    currtime_2 = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y  %H:%M")
    try:
        wid_2 = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
        wname_2 = subprocess.check_output(get_name).decode("utf-8"); wname_2 = wname_2[:wname_2.rfind(" |  ")]
        if any([wid_2 != wid_1, currtime_2 != currtime_1, wname_2 != wname_1]):
            cmd2 = ["xdotool", "set_window", "--name", wname_2+" |  "+str(currtime_2), wid_2]
            subprocess.Popen(cmd2)
        currtime_1 = currtime_2; wid_1 = wid_2
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
```

#### How to use

1. The script uses `xdotool`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `show_datetime.py`
3. Test-run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/show_datetime.py
   ```

   Open a new window or give an existing one focus. The date & time should appear in the window's title within 1-2 seconds. Wait a minute to see if the time is updated.
4. If all works fine, add it to your startup applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add, add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/show_datetime.py
   ```
5. If you are having difficulties running it from start up, use the command (in startup applications):

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 20&&python3 /path/to/show_datetime.py"
   ```

#### Explanation

The script keeps an eye on three things:

- The frontmost window's *id*
- The frontmost window's *name*
- The current *time* (minute)

If there is a change in either one, the date/time is appended or updated to the currently frontmost window.

*Why use the name -and- the id of the window?*

- The window- *id* is used to set the window's title, to prevent setting the wrong window (terminal windows e.g. can be named similarly).
- The window- *name* is to include tabbed windows, e.g. `Firefox`. The window *name* will change when another tab is chosen or opened, while the window- *id* won't change.
- The *conditional* `if any([])` is to edit the window's title only if there is a reason to.

Comment: Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 5):

### It's a simple shell script:

---

### Requirements

- `xdotool`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```
- `wmctrl`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  ```

---

### Main part

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "$(awk -F' \\|\\|' '{print $1}' <<< $(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)) || $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
```

The `||` is the separator between the window title an the date/time part. If you need another one, change it, eg:

`#`

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "$(awk -F' #' '{print $1}' <<< $(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)) # $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
```

---

### The script

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -N "$(awk -F' \\|\\|' '{print $1}' <<< $(xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowname)) || $(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
    sleep 5
done
```

Comment: `sudo apt install wmctrl` was needed. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script that utilizes bash, xprop, and wmctrl (does not come with ubuntu). This script can be added as an autostart entry or placed into `.desktop` file. Basic idea is to get current active window's id, store its current title, and use output of date command and title to form a new title. The if statement prevents infinite loop of appending date.
You can get `wmctrl` with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl` . Otherwise this script is very simplistic but does the job well enough.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Date : June 9 2015
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Description: script to append time to window titles
while sleep 1; do
        ACTIVEID=$(xprop -root | awk '/^_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW/ {gsub("0x","0x0");print $5}')
        MATCHED_TITLE="$( wmctrl -l | awk -v searchterm=$ACTIVEID   '$0~searchterm {for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" "}')"
        date --date="$(echo $MATCHED_TITLE | awk '{print $1" "$2}')"  > /dev/null  2>&1

        if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
                MATCHED_TITLE="$(echo $MATCHED_TITLE | awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" "}')"
        fi      
        sleep 1
        wmctrl -i -r $ACTIVEID -T "$(date +"%D %H:%M" 2>/dev/null) $MATCHED_TITLE "

done
```

Comment: Gets the job done. The window title is lost though.

Comment: @dael99 interesting. Is it lost only in terminal ? or on other programs as well ? Please let me know, so I can improve my answer

Comment: Lost in other windows as well (like Firefox)

Comment: @dael99 interesting. I've tested this multiple times, still works on all the windows. Can you please add `set -x` at the beginning of the script, after `#!/bin/bash` , and let me know if any of the variables are not being set ?