# Is it possible to identify windows using regular expressions in xdotool?

Tags: command-line, xdotool

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Say I have the following five open windows with *mozilla* in their title:

```
$ wmctrl -lx
0x03e00018  0 Navigator.Firefox     kububb Ubuntu Manpage: xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool - Mozilla Firefox
0x05a00003  0 leafpad.Leafpad       kububb mozilla1.txt
0x05e00003  0 mousepad.Mousepad     kububb mozilla2.txt - Mousepad
0x06000005  0 kate.kate                N/A mozilla3.txt  — Kate
0x06400093  0 gedit.Gedit           kububb mozilla4.txt (~/Desktop) - gedit
```

`man xdotool` has this in the WINDOW COMMANDS section:

> search [options] pattern
>   Search for windows with titles, names, or classes with a regular expression pattern.

and this:

> --name
>   Match against the window name. This is the same string that is displayed in the window titlebar.

Is it possible to exclude only the first entry, the Firefox one?

If I run

```
xdotool search --name mozilla
```

five identifiers are listed. How can I list just the four *mozilla*.txt* ones?

Comment: Based on a couple of quick tests, it *appears* to support GNU-style extended regular expressions. So for example `'mozilla.+\.txt'` or `'mozilla[0-9]\.txt'`

Comment: Both work just fine!

Comment: OK in that case I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a couple of quick tests, it appears to support GNU-style extended regular expressions. Ex. given

```
$ wmctrl -ilx | grep brave
0x04000001  0 brave-browser.Brave-browser  t400s Newest Questions - Ask Ubuntu - Brave
0x040000fe  0 brave-browser.Brave-browser  t400s file2.txt - Brave
0x040000ff  0 brave-browser.Brave-browser  t400s fileA.txt - Brave
```

then

```
$ xdotool search -name 'file.+\.txt'
67109118
67109119
```

or

```
$ xdotool search -name 'file[0-9]\.txt'
67109118
```