# How to execute a "name.desktop" file?

Tags: command-line, sharing

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
Name=ShareFolder
Icon=/usr/share/icons/DPL/NetworkShare.png
Name[en_US]=ShareFolder
URL=smb://servername/sharefolder
```

This is my `.desktop` file which has a URL. How do I execute this desktop shortcut in the terminal? If i double click it works perfectly, but I need to execute this in terminal.

I tried [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal). That didn't work for me either but it does if its an "application" shortcut. I'm trying here to execute "link" `.desktop` file, where you define in the type section (`Type=Link`) and (`URL=smb://servername/sharefolder`)

Comment: So you want it to open the URL when you run it in terminal?

Comment: not open actually excute it.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
xdg-open path/to/file.desktop
```

The first line in the file is the application that runs that file.

If this does not work, try this (adopted from [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal)):

```
xdg-open `grep '^URL' path/to/file.desktop | tail -1 | sed 's/^URL=//' | sed 's/%.//'` &
```

Comment: This way it wont work. it will open the .desktop file in edit mode.does not execute it.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal

Comment: i tried that article . that didn't work for me either but it does if its an "application" shortcut. im trying here to execute "link" .desktop file. where you define in the type section.(Type=Link) and (URL=smb://servername/sharefolder)

Comment: I edited answer, hope that will help.

Comment: didn't work that either. What im trying to achieve here is URL link file to a share folder .(Type=Link) and (URL=smb://servername/sharefolder)

Comment: Does `xdg-open smb://servername/sharefolder` work?

Comment: gvfs-open: smb://servername/sharefolder: error opening location: The specified location is not mounted.

Comment: Then it's better to use `autofs` and change URL to something like `/smb/servername/sharedfolder`. It has advantage that folder will be mounted automatically.

Comment: that wont give me the share authorities exactly to the login user from the domain. it overrides with the mounting user authorities. if i put it in fstab thats going to take su access.

Comment: Not if you will use credentials file. I assume you are entering credentials each time you connect. The credentials file can bypass it.