# Trouble installing Tor browser

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, browser, tor

I am running ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my HP laptop. I've been trying to get Tor browser but have had some complications. I've downloaded the file and saved it to my desktop

I've tried several commands trying to get into the created directory and install the browser:

```
cd tor-browser-linux64-4.5.3_en-US
```

I've used variations of this file name to include the `.tar`, to include `.desktop` at the end and various other things.

I've also tried to the command

```
tar -xvf <TAR_FILE_NAME>
```

and all return with the message of "No such file or directory". What's the deal??

I'm running a 64-bit OS and downloaded the 64-bit version. I can open the folder and view the various files. I'm not skilled in Ubuntu syntax whatsoever.

Comment: have you tried command: sudo apt-get install tor-browser

Answer (score 5):

You need to download the tor browser bundle. You can get it from [here](https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/4.5.3/tor-browser-linux64-4.5.3_en-US.tar.xz).

We will `cd` into that folder to which you downloaded the file. Assuming it is your Downloads directory, open a new terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Now we extract the contents of the file:

```
tar -xvf tor-browser-linux64-*.tar.xz
```

It creates a new folder called tor-browser_en-US. We `cd` into this folder. This is important as the script to start tor browser should be executed with the present working directory as this folder:

```
cd tor-browser_en-US
```

Finally we start the browser:

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop
```

Or you could ignore the last two steps, browse to the folder tor-browser_en-US from the GUI and click on `Start Tor Browser`

Comment: You can start a desktop file? Have you tried that before posting?

Comment: @A.B. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) answer, it's not possible directly, but it does work from here, in this context. I've never thought more about it before you asked. [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/IwnTKfd.png) a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, interesting :)

Comment: @A.B. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020106/hashbang-for-gnome-desktop-files) is how it's done. The only difference being that `execdesktop` is provided in the bundle. The hashbang uses a relative path, and this is why it is necessary to `cd` into `tor-browser_en-US` for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Tor Browser Bundle via PPA, the simplest way.

> Tor Browser Bundle is a web browser based on Firefox ESR (Firefox with
>   extended support), configured to protect users' privacy and anonymity
>   by using Tor and Vidalia, tools that come bundled with it. The bundle
>   also includes 4 Firefox extensions: TorButton, TorLauncher, NoScript
>   and HTTPS-Everywhere.

Open a terminal and start the command below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

After that, start the browser via Dash.

<sub>[Source](http://m.webupd8.org/2013/12/tor-browser-bundle-ubuntu-ppa.html?m=1)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `torbrowser-launcher`. It may be available via your distribution's package manager but that is probably out-of-date so I strongly recommend you install via PPA.

It will download the most recent version of the Tor Browser Bundle, automatically update (preserving your bookmarks and preferences), and verify the TBB's GnuPG signature. It includes AppArmor profiles as well as application launchers for your desktop environment's menu.

This is an improvement over the other PPA provided because it works with multiple languages and architectures. It also migrates all of your bookmarks and preferences. The webupd8 PPA supports English only and deletes any changes upon upgrade.

You should probably check out the [torbrowser-launcher project GitHub page](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher) for more information first, but you can install it like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:micahflee/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```