# What is #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open in desktop file?

Tags: .desktop

I created a simple desktop file to check the connectivity of remote location in which `Exec=ping 192.168.0.9`. But one file created with `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` before Desktop Entry and another without `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` and both worked the same. Then What is the use of it in desktop file? What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/295286) answer , the use of `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` was meant to serve as a way to launch applications that referenced in `.desktop` file via command line. But as of now, it doesn't work and only opens `.desktop` file as text file in `gedit`. Nowadays , if you want to launch a `.desktop` app via command line, you must do some pre-processing of the file itself.

As for use of `#!` it basically tells your computer which interpreter to use with this file. In this case, `/usr/bin/env` which will return path to `xdg-open` command (i.e, this calls `xdg-open` to read and execute your file ) .

Comment: Ok. Got it but you said "to launch a `.desktop` app via command line, you must do some pre-processing of the file itself. and what is that pre-process? Could you tell me?

Comment: Preprocessing is just extracting the `Exec=` line. And there's plenty of tools for that: grep, awk,sed,python,perl. Just whatever works for you.