# Open multiple tabs in ubuntu file explorer from command line

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome, nautilus, 22.04

I'd like to open multiple tabs in Ubuntu's File Explorer (20.04 or 22.04) from terminal.

Optimally, I'd like to use some built-in utility like `gio` or `nautilus`.

I am aware of [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/103), but it seems closed without further action. I want to avoid scripts like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26042/can-a-single-nautilus-window-be-started-with-multiple-tabs).

The closest I could get is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/826324/1116175), however it's six years old now and I still hope there should be a simpler solution.

The best solution would look something like: `gio open ~/Downloads/music/ ~/workspace/etc/`. This kind of works, I admit, but it opens the directories in separate windows; whereas I want separate tabs of the same window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 22.04,
you could try this:-

```bash
  nemo -t  ~/Downloads ~/Pictures
```

Comment: Can confirm this also works on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't even considered `nemo`, but after using it for a few days it does look good.

Since `nemo` is popular and official (as open source could get :D) and does answer my question in a simple way, accepting the answer.

By the way, it works on my Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks!