# reveal file in default file manager with command line

Tags: command-line, filemanager, xdg-open

I would like to open folder in default file manager an focus on specific file.

I can do it with Notilus or Nemo (for example)

```
notilus ~/folder/file.txt
nemo ~/folder/file.txt
```

but I want to use default file manager.

I can use `xdg-open` but

```
xdg-open ./folder
```

will open folder with defaut file explorer bu doesn't focus on file, and

```
xdg-open ./folder/file.txt
```

will open file with defaut .txt editor

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me having `nemo` as default:

```
gtk-launch "$(xdg-mime query default inode/directory)" ./folder/file.txt
```

You can create an alias for it if you like.

See:

- [Find the default application for a certain extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297932/find-the-default-application-for-a-certain-extension)
- [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal)

Comment: Thanks! it works with **Notilus** and **Nemo** but not with **Thunar**

Comment: In Xubuntu? Can you try `exo-open` ?

Comment: i try `exo-open --launch FileManager ./folder/file.txt`
it open text editor if Thunar is default