# How can I find the command to be used in a desktop icon that will launch a snap application?

Tags: gnome-shell, snap, .desktop

I want make a desktop icon, that will launch a program. Currently I can launch app from icon in "Show Applications", but I want icon on desktop.
I know, I should use

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

for creating shortcuts.

The problem is - I don't know command that will launch this particular app from terminal. And obviously, I need this unknown to me command for creating shortcuts.
I installed from snap, so I can't just copy icon from `/usr/share/applications.`

Any advice how to find such command or move icon from "Show Applications" to desktop?

Comment: You need to clarify which one you want - open the `.desktop` file from terminal,  how to create a shortcut for snap, or how to place it onto desktop - because these are all separate issues and the post is considered too broad, and might be closed.  I can give a hint on the  first one : opening `.desktop` from terminal can be done either via `gtk-launch` or python script(https://askubuntu.com/a/239883/295286).

Comment: @sergiy I don't think it's too broad. As I understood OP just wants to create a launcher for a snap application in desktop. They toyed with a couple of ideas: (1) copying the launcher from system, but they failed as it's not there in `/usr/share/applications` (since it's a snap application), and (2) they tried to create a launcher by hand using `gnome-desktop-item-edit`, and again they failed as they didn't know what was to be used in the '*command*' box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you installed the application from snap and it can be found in '*Show Applications*', the `.desktop` launcher for the application should be found in the `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/` directory. Just copy the `.desktop` launcher from there to your desktop.

Also you should be able to find the executable for the application in the `/snap/bin/` directory. So if you want to manually create the `.desktop` launcher in your desktop, then you can use `/snap/bin/<application>` (e.g. `/snap/bin/firefox`) as the command. You can find the `<application>` part by running

```
snap list
```

Alternatively, you can use `snap run <application>` as the command (and of course, also to run the application from Terminal).