# start Apostrophe markdown editor from comand line

Tags: command-line, bash, desktop-icons

I installed `Apostrophe` markdown editor to my Ubuntu. I have an icon on my desktop which opens a markdown file with `Kate` editor.

This is the command I use: `/usr/bin/kate <path-to-file>.md`. This works fine.

But now, I would like to open the file with `Apostrophe`. How to start `Apostrophe` from the command line?

When I start the app from the main menu, then I can see that the following processes appear:

```
ps axu | grep apostr

user        5380  0.3  0.0   3768  1788 ?        S    23:57   0:00 bwrap --args 31 apostrophe
user        5381 12.7  1.2 102450484 101460 ?    Sl   23:57   0:01 python3 /app/bin/apostrophe
user        5390  0.0  0.4 102363952 38164 ?     S    23:57   0:00 python3 /app/bin/apostrophe
user        5391  0.0  0.4 102363952 38132 ?     S    23:57   0:00 python3 /app/bin/apostrophe
user        5396  0.0  0.0   9368   660 pts/0    S+   23:57   0:00 grep --color=auto apostr
```

But I am not able to start it with the same command.
What is the proper command to start it and open a given file automatically?

Comment: Find the parent process of the `python3 /app/bin/apostrophe` by entering `ps -ef|grep apostr` . The third column is the parent process ID. Do a grep for that, and so on, until you reach the top level command.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Running a .desktop file in the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command:

```
flatpak run org.gnome.gitlab.somas.Apostrophe <your file>
```